# FastCgi vs PHP-FPM using Nginx web server

Tags: nginx, memcached, fastcgi, php, xcache

I am using this [tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-13.04-nginx-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p4) to install nginx, php and mysql on my new web server.

The tutorial is using ISPConfig 3 and there is an option to whether use FastCgi or PHP-FPM.

I am wondering which is better of the two. In terms of performance and speed, which of the two is the best to use inline with nginx?

BTW, I have also memcached and xcache enabled on my server.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

PHP-FPM is much better than the old FastCGI handling of PHP. As of PHP 5.3.3 PHP-FPM is in core and the old FastCGI implementation isn’t available anymore.

My answer was just down voted (after being online for quite some time) and I understand why, so here is a list why PHP-FPM is actually better than the old FastCGI implementation.

First of all, it was known for quite some time that the FastCGI implementation is bad in the PHP community. A page that documents that can be found at https://wiki.php.net/ideas/fastcgiwork where it says:

> php-cgi is not useful in production environment without additional “crutches” (e.g. spawn-fcgi from lighttpd distribution or php-fpm patch). This project assumes integration of such “crutches” and extending php-cgi to support for different protocols.
>
> - daemonization (detach, pid file creation, setup environment variables, setuid/setgid/chroot)
> - graceful restart
> - separate and improve transport layer to allow support for different protocols
> - support for SCGI protocol
> - support for subset of HTTP protocol
> - …

Here is a list of the things that PHP-FPM does better that was taken from http://php-fpm.org/about/:

> - PHP daemonization: pid file, log file, `setsid()`, `setuid()`, `setgid()`, `chroot()`
> - Process Management. Ability to “gracefully” stop and start PHP workers without losing any queries. This allows gradually updating the configuration and binary without losing any queries.
> - Restricting IP addresses from which requests can come from.
> - Dynamic number of processes, depending on the load (adaptive process spawning).
> - Starting the workers with different uid/gid/chroot/environment and different `php.ini` options (no need for safe mode).
> - Logging `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.
> - Ability to emergency restart all the processes in the event of an accidental destruction of the shared memory opcode cache, if using an accelerator.
> - Forcing the completion of process if `set_time_limit()` fails.
>
> Additional features:
>   - Error header
>   - Accelerated upload support
>   - [`fastcgi_finish_request()`](https://php.net/function.fastcgi-finish-request)
>   - Slowlog with backtrace

Answer (score 8):

One small correction: the PHP FastCGI SAPI is still available, even on PHP 5.5.x.

```
[root@zulu1 ~]# /usr/local/php54/bin/php-cgi -v 
PHP 5.4.17 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jul 18 2013 05:12:07) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group 
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Even on PHP 5.6.x there's still fcgi SAPI: PHP 5.6.23 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jul  8 2016 08:49:00). However, I always tend to use php-fpm, it's much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

**On the fastcgi side:**

1. Fastcgi is easier to monitor:
   There is one pid per user in fastcgi. On a web server with many accounts it is easy to find overloaded processes. On the other hand, php-fpm creates many processes depending on the requests + one master process. This is messy when you have lots of connections from different IP.
2. Fastcgi configuration is easier:
   Fastcgi is included in apache configuration. So it makes things easier. On the other hand, php-fpm requires additional configuration files. If there are configuration dependencies it makes things complicated.
3. The big shared hosting companies still don't use php-fpm in 2015 with php 5.6
   Today, all the biggest shared web hosting companies (bluehost,hostgator,namecheap) use fastcgi. I think there are reasons why they don't offer php-fpm as php-handler.

**On the php-fpm side:**

1. i have noticed that php-fpm consumed 20% less than fastcgi which consumed 20% less than mod_php. So, php-fpm is good for web server with the smallest amount of ram.